# Softlayer API: list images sort by image name

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using the following Softlayer API to list all the images:

https://id:key@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/getPublicImages.json

Is there a way to return all the images sorted by image name ascend?

Thanks!

Q.Z.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/getPublicImages?objectFilter={"name":{"operation":"orderBy","options":[{"name":"sort","value":["ASC"]}]}}

Method: Get
```

Replace: $user and $apiKey with your own information